# Parse date with any separator

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have an object that stores info about its content.

```
var columnType = new ColumnType
    {
        ColumnName = "DateTime D/M/Y",
        ColType = typeof (DateTime),
        Format = "ddMMyyyy HH:mm"
    }
```

Based on that I need to parse rows before adding them to this column. The problem is that my format doesn't include separators. I want to parse the date no matter what separator.

The standard `DateTime.Parse` doesn't have a constructor with format, and `DateTime.ParseExact` expects that the specified format already has separators in it.

I need something that will parse date like that:
If my format is `ddMMyyyy HH:mm`, then:

`05.03.2016 04:19` -> parsed

`05-03-2016 04:19` -> parsed

`05/03/2016` -> parsed (time should be optional)

`2016/03/05 04:19` -> error

I tried to do this, but without separators in `format` it didn't work:

```
var format = "ddMMyyyy HH:mm";
DateTime.TryParseExact("05.03.2016 04:19", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime resultValue);
```

Comment: "and DateTime.ParseExact expects that the specified format already has separators in it" - that's not true. When it's unambiguous, it's fine to parse without separators. For example: `var date = DateTime.ParseExact("19061976 08:10", "ddMMyyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: But if your format doesn't include separators, why are you trying to parse values that *do* have separators? "05.03.2016 04:19" doesn't match the format "ddMMyyyy HH:mm". It's unclear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: And even if you're talking about basically just ignoring separators, it's unclear how you'd expect "05/03/2016" to parse - because after removing the separators, that's "05032016" which still doesn't match "ddMMyyyy HH:mm".

Comment: I don't specify separators, because I want to parse date with any separator, doesn't matter if the separator is a dot or a semicolon or whatever. Also you are right I didnt properly describe `05/03/2016`. Time should be optional.

Comment: Well "time being optional" is a whole different matter than separators being optional. That should be handled separately, using the overload that takes multiple patterns. But what do you deem to be a valid separator? Would you expect "05+03+2016 04:19" to be okay? What about "05/03/2016 04_19"? What about "05X03YZ2016 04:19"? What about "0590392016 04:19" (so "9" as the separator)? What about if there are extra separators that you don't care about, e.g. "/05/03/2016/// 04:19"? You need to be really precise about your requirements.

Comment: I think I could go with a predefined array of separators, such as `['.', ',', '-', '/']`

Comment: Okay, and can they only be in specific positions? What about the time separator? You should update your question with these precise requirements. I'm about to get on a plane, so I won't be able to answer for another 5 hours at least, but with a better question you're more likely to get an answer from someone else.

Comment: Thank you for help, I will update my question. I just hoped there was a constructor I missed that would combine `DateTime.Parse` and my format. I guess I have to solve it with more than a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you. This first snippet doesn't deal with optional time, see below.

```
char[] separators = { '/', '-', '.', '@', '#' };
string format = "dd?MM?yyyy HH:mm"; // ? replaced with each separator
// Create and populate an array of all acceptable formats
string[] formats = new string[separators.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < separators.Length; i++)
{
    formats[i] = format.Replace('?', separators[i]);
}
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("05#12#2017 15:36", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Use dt
}
else
{
    // No format matched
}
```

This works by using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a string array of formats, rather than one single format. This works because:

> The format of the string representation must match at least one of the specified formats exactly.

It must be noted that all the separators must be the same in the input string, no mix and match.

For optional time you could add other formats that do not include `HH:mm`. For example:

```
...
string formatWithTime = "dd?MM?yyyy HH:mm";
string formatWithoutTime = "dd?MM?yyyy";
List<string> f = new List<string>();
foreach (char c in separators)
{
    f.Add(formatWithTime.Replace('?', c));
    f.Add(formatWithoutTime.Replace('?', c));
}
string[] formats = f.ToArray();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse` works with the samples depending on the `IFormatProvider`:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("pl");
var d1 = DateTime.Parse("05.03.2016 04:19", ci);
var d2 = DateTime.Parse("05-03-2016 04:19", ci);
var d3 = DateTime.Parse("05/03/2016"      , ci);
var d4 = DateTime.Parse("2016/03/05 04:19", ci);
```

Comment: I try to make it to work with as wide range of date combinations as possible. This is for parsing different files, so I don't really know what the culture of the file's dates is.

Comment: @FCin DateTime.Parse handles a lot more cases including words, so I think it is best to handle only the cases where `DateTime.TryParse` fails.